# Method <br> text wrapping swal.fire javascript library

Tags: javascript

I'm using a javascript library swal.fire for custom alerts, I was wondering why it doesn't make me wrap when I write the code in the text with `+ <br>` is there an easy solution that I can use? it doesn't work either `\n` or `\r` any suggestions?

Code JS :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.show_confirm').click(function(e) {

        var form = $(this).closest("form");

        var name = $(this).data("name");

        e.preventDefault();

        Swal.fire({
            title: `Terminare la modalità training ?`,
            text: 'Terminando la modalità training si passerà alla modalità REAL e verranno:' + "<br>" + '1. azzerati gli esiti e relativi KPI nella dashboard',
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: 'rgba(244, 116, 78, 1)',
            cancelButtonColor: 'lightgrey',
            confirmButtonText: 'Termina',
            cancelButtonText: 'Annulla'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                e.preventDefault();
                form.submit();
            };
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: From your code, it seems that you're using SweetAlert2. Have you checked the [official documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)? Specifically, the part "Custom HTML description and buttons with ARIA labels". In short - just use `html: ....` instead of `text: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS issue try this

```js
//your JS object Property should look like this
{
...
text: `Terminando la modalità training si passerà alla modalità REAL e verranno: \n 1. azzerati gli esiti e relativi KPI nella dashboard`,
}
```

```css
/* your global or your prefered CSS file */
.swal-text {
  white-space: pre-line;
 }
```